# Что делать с ответами на английском языке? Стоит ли добавить тревогу "принято отвечать на русском"?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, тревоги, ответы

В очереди проверки сообщений низкого качества встретил ответ на английском. Вот [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1185557/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-exception-%D0%B2-postgres-connection-to-localhost5432-refused-%D0%B2-%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5/1205777#1205777). Что делать? Нажать "выглядит нормально" и перевести на русский? В причинах закрытия нет

> "На stackoverflow на русском принято отвечать на русском языке,
> пожалуйста, переведите Ваш ответ на русский язык",

хотя по вопросам такая причина закрытия есть. Считаю это не справедливо, нужно добавить аналогичную тревогу для ответов или хотя бы дополнить тревогу по вопросам.

Comment: Не помешает, добавляйте

Comment: @avp, а как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Я не знаю (не занимаюсь закрытиями). Ждите ответов от более компетентных в области управления сайтом участников

Comment: @avp количество тревог ограничено, да и наврядли имеет смысл добавлять новую, для ситуации которая раз в год встречается

Comment: @Kromster можно не добавлять новую, а дополнить старую, внеся в тревогу по вопросам и ответы

Comment: Потому что закрывать можно только вопросы, а не ответы.

Comment: среди программистов считается нормально владеть английским, поэтому ответ может быть на английском как мне кажется, но могу ошибаться)